# Prove if 5;5;3;3;2;2;2 forms a graphical sequence.

Tags: graph-theory

As per Handshaking Lemma, I suspect such graph cannot be formed (because even no. of vertex is having even degree and not odd : vertex 6 has degree 2). But I am able to draw a graph. Does such graphs exists?

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you can draw a graph with that degree sequence proves that the sequence is graphical. What makes you think it's not? The Handshaking Lemma says that the sum of the degrees is an even number, equal to twice the number of edges. Sure enough, $5+5+3+3+2+2+2=22$ is an even number, so everything is fine. I guess the graph you drew has $11$ edges?

Comment: Hi Bof, 
Thank you for the help. Yes I have got 11 edges.

Comment: Also @Bof, the sequence : 5,5,3,3,2,2 cannot be graphic. As its not satisfying the Handshaking Lemma.
Am I correct?

Comment: The sequence $5,5,3,3,2,2$ is graphic; it is the degree sequence of a graph with six vertices $a,b,c,d,e,f$ and ten edges $ab,ac,ad,ae,af,bc,bd,be,bf,cd$. Please tell me, what do you think the Handshaking Lemma says?

Comment: I had understood it to be that the sum of even number of vertices must be odd.
However, in the first case I had thought that any even numbered vertex must have an odd degree.

Comment: Source : (Wiki)In graph theory, a branch of mathematics, the handshaking lemma is the statement that every finite undirected graph has an even number of vertices with odd degree (the number of edges touching the vertex).

Comment: Right. The handshaking lemma says that the number of vertices of odd degree must be even (which is the same as saying that the sum of all the degrees must be even). The sequence $5,5,3,3,2,2$ has $4$ odd numbers. Since $4$ is even, the handshaking lemma is satisfied.

Comment: Thanks . I have completed these questions :)